# Existe uma estrutura de dados "stack" padrão em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, stack

Se não, conhecem um bom módulo não-padrão? Precisaria de trabalhar com o `stack`, mas acho muito estranho não existir um módulo `stack` (pilha) padrão em Python e ao mesmo tempo existir um módulo `queue` (fila).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não. A recomendação padrão da linguagem é [utilizar uma lista como uma pilha (stack)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks).

No caso de uma fila (*queue*), é preciso métodos adicionais e restrições para que a fila seja manipulada corretamente. [Há diversos tipos de fila](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/queue.html), a saber:

- `Queue` (FIFO, *First In, First Out*)
- `LifoQueue` (*Last In, First Out*)
- `PriorityQueue` (por ordem crescente de valor)

Comment: Se você quer o comportamento *Last In, First Out*, sim.

Comment: Então. Isso por si só já torna desnecessária a implementação da `stack` em separado.

Comment: @nbro Pelo que eu entendi dos links citados, a principal diferença entre usar uma lista como pilha e usar um `LifoQueue` é que esse último é *thread-safe* - e portanto deve ser menos eficiente caso você esteja trabalhando com um único *thread*.